# ORM code for Azure Dev storage emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator

Tricky question - Does anyone know where the ORM SQL code lives that the Azure Dev storage emulator uses for Table Storage?

I'm wanting to implement a SQL version of Azure Table storage for use on-premises (outside of Azure).

And before explaining to me the differences between a relational db like SQL Server and a NoSQL key/value store like Azure Table storage - I know already, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the SQL server you installed the Storage Emulator. You will see a database called "DevelopmentStorageDb20110816" if you have installed the Azure SDK v1.5+ (It was a different date previous to that - something like DevelopmentStorageDb20090919 I think).

In that database you will find all the tables, stored procedures and functions needed to emulate Windows Azure storage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Whilst this DB is useful to emulate the schema, it doesn't encapsulate all the logic for this database to be used in an identical fashion to Azure Table Storage i.e. there will be a bunch of ORM code somewhere that I'm guessing will consist of some LINQ to SQL and potentially other raw SQL code for interacting with this database. It's this code that I'm interested in.

Comment: I see. You could run SQL Profiler when accessing the storage through the API and see what the generated SQL looks like. I'd guess it is just calling the stored procedures though.